# Error while using "context" in my react-es6 project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, es6-class

I am trying to use "context" in my es6 react code but while bundling I'm getting this error

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        LayoutURL : React.PropTypes.string 
    }; 
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {

        }
    }
}
```

> "Module build failed: TypeError: _jsTokens2.default.matchToToken is not a function"

PFB my webpack code( I have added es6 in resolve but still the err is persisting) my webpack version is "^1.13.0"

```
 module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8085
    },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','.es6']
},
};
```

Comment: which version of react you are using?

Comment: "react": "^15.0.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that err was due to the syntax. The updated syntax:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { //state initialization }
  }
}

Layout.contextTypes={
  LayoutURL : React.PropTypes.string 
};
```